# Auto renewable subscription android Version_3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I just started working on Android few days ago & I am doing some RND work on **Auto Renewable Subscription**.

I goggled & found some official links, blog-posts, etc. But I didn't find the tutorial for  **Auto Renewable Subscription**.

Following are the links:
1. Implementing [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)
2. Preparing Your [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)
3. Simple In App Billing / [Payment V3](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/)

I found the In-app Billing tutorial & integrated it in my code... but I didn't find any information related to **Auto-Renewable-Subscription**.

I just want to know the following things:
1. Is Auto-Subscription Possible in android.
2. If yes, then, How to implement the Auto-Subscription service.

Please let me know your views.
Thanks..!!!

Comment: The most useful link that i found for this question is; https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html because V3 is the latest version for IAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, Auto-Subscription Possible in android
2) You can refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/) project for more details 

Google play sample application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.iboxmanstudio.trivialdrive&hl=en

Try [TrivialDrive sample project](https://github.com/congenialmobile/TrivialDrive) also.

Comment: i have tried this Trivial Example and it was working previously but currently it is not working dear.